# Two functions in the same line

Tags: math-mode

```
      \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
  \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}

   \begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
   h\colon S(0,1)& \rightarrow S^A(0,1)\\
    x&\mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|_A},
   \end{align*}
   and
   \begin{align*}
  g\colon S^A(0,1)& \rightarrow S(0,1)\\
 y&\mapsto \frac{y}{\|y\|},
\end{align*}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

> I want to make the two equations in the same line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `aligned`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[t]
  h\colon S(0,1) &\rightarrow S^A(0,1)\\
  x              &\mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|_A},
\end{aligned}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{aligned}[t]
  g\colon S^A(0,1) &\rightarrow S(0,1)\\
  y                &\mapsto \frac{y}{\|y\|},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used to be fond of this function notation, but then I started to dislike it: it's heavy, uses up space and doesn't really do anything good. On the blackboard it can be useful, not in papers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So what is the best way to define a function?

Comment: @Schüler I tend to use the inline form, but that's personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

Using `aligned` you can do the job in `inline` math mode. I suppose you would like the result centered, so, I placed the code in a `center` environment and finally, I added some `\hspace` commands for better spacing:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
  \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}

   \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \(\begin{aligned}
   h\colon S(0,1)& \rightarrow S^A(0,1)\\
    x&\mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|_A},
   \end{aligned}
   \hspace{20pt}\text{ and }\hspace{20pt}
   \begin{aligned}
  g\colon S^A(0,1)& \rightarrow S(0,1)\\
 y&\mapsto \frac{y}{\|y\|},
\end{aligned}\)
\end{center}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like one of these?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{aligned}
h\colon S(0,1)& \longrightarrow S^A(0,1)\\
x&\longmapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|_A},
\end{aligned}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
\begin{aligned}
g\colon S^A(0,1)& \longrightarrow S(0,1)\\
y&\longmapsto \frac{y}{\|y\|},
\end{aligned} \]\bigskip

\[ \begin{rcases} \begin{aligned}
h\colon S(0,1)& \longrightarrow S^A(0,1)\\
x&\longmapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|_A},
\end{aligned}\end{rcases}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\begin{dcases} \begin{aligned}
g\colon S^A(0,1)& \longrightarrow S(0,1)\\
y&\longmapsto \frac{y}{\|y\|},
\end{aligned}\end{dcases} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]